# How to sort a list of BigDecimal objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, bigdecimal

Given the following input:

```
-100
50
0
56.6
90
```

I have added each value as a `BigDecimal` to a list.

I want to be able to sort the list from highest to lowest value.

I have attempted to do this in the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            list.add(new BigDecimal(sc.next()));
        }

        Collections.reverse(list);

        for(BigDecimal d : list){

            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
90
56.6
0
50
-100
```

In this instance 50 should be a higher value than 0.

How can I correctly sort a BigDecimal list from highest to lowest taking into account decimal and non decimal values?

Comment: `Collections.reverse` just reverses the list. Use `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.reverseOrder());`

Comment: I think you want `sort`, not `reverse`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your code you are only calling reverse which reverses the order of the list. You need to sort the list as well, in [reversed order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-).

This will do the trick:

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: But `reverseOrder` has been around since 1.5.

Comment: You're right, I just looked at the Comparator.reverseOrder() API. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Pro tip: If you realize your answer is not as good as it could be, try to update it so that it is. For a 3 line answer, there's no need to add "Edit: ..." in front of the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.commons.collections.list.TreeList`. No need to sort. It will keep inserted objects in sorted order. Then you can just reverse it if you want.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Despite the similarity in name to the JDK's TreeMap, the javadocs seem to indicate that TreeList works as any other List would: it keeps elements ordered by how you add/insert them. It just uses a different implementation internally to hold onto those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it worked for me:

```
package HackerRank;

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class Sorting
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeSet<BigDecimal> list = new TreeSet<BigDecimal>();
        int testCase = sc.nextInt();

        while(testCase-- > 0)
            list.add(new BigDecimal(sc.next()));

        System.out.println(list); //ascending order
        System.out.println(list.descendingSet()); //descending order
    }
}
```